# How can I get multiple data, from a php file, with ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

I want to get data from submit.php page and put them in some tags in my page. in the example below I can put just on data in tag that has id: "shortcutTitle".
I get more than one data from my php file(from database) and I want them to sit on various tags in my page.

```
function submit(shortcutid,shortcuttitle,shortcutlink,icon)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
         xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
             document.getElementById("shortcutTitle").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","submit.php?shid="+shortcutid+"&shtitle="+shortcuttitle+"&shlink="+shortcutlink+"&shicon="+icon,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you question doesn't make much sense at the moment - you need to expand on the explanation of exactly what your are trying to achieve ... perhaps include your PHP to show what you are attempting to pass between PHP and JavaScript ?

Comment: what do you mean by "multiple data"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to use `json_encode` to send a javascript object back to the XML request

```
<?php
  echo json_encode( array('name' => 'tehlulz', 'id' => '1') );
?>
```

So from the results, you can then call the output by:

```
var ajaxResuts = {};

if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
  ajaxResuts = JSON.parse( xmlhttp.responseText );
  alert("Returned: " + ajaxResults.name);
}
```